# What is the O() complexity of this function?

Tags: swift, big-o

This is a simple function that checks to see if the string is unique. I reason that the complexity should be N * N -> N^2. Is this correct? Even if the second N will always be smaller than the first.

```
func isUnique(_ str: String) -> Bool {

    let charArr = Array(str.characters)

    for (i1 , char) in charArr.enumerated() {

        guard i1 != charArr.count - 1 else {
            break
        }

        for (i2, char) in charArr[(i1 + 1)..<charArr.count].enumerated() {
            if charArr[i1] == char {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, There are a lot of myths behind this problem and when you analysis on **Big O** topic, you getting so many varying answers. And the most popular question is:

> "If two nested for loops contains break statement. so still my complexity
>   is n*n or O(n2)?"

I think the simple answer is"

**Big-O notation isn't about finding exact values given your actual parameters. It is about determining asymptotic runtime.**